# How to add back to DOM an existing D3 SVG chart?

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

Hi have a D3 SVG object:

```
 d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr('id', 'chartId' + idx)
```

To which I append rects to create a bar chart.

I would like to be able to add and remove it from the DOM.

I am able to remove it easily with:

```
d3.select('svg#chartId' + j).remove();
```

How can I re-append the entire SVG chart I just removed?

Comment: Why not just `hide()` and `show()`?

Comment: d3.select('svg#chartId' + j).hide() is not a function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `detach()` instead of `remove()`

```
var refToElelment = $(d3.select('svg#chartId' + j)).detach();
```

OR

```
$('#chartId' + j).detach()
```

Later..

```
$('#target').append(refToElelment);
```

Comment: it tells me that  d3.select('svg#chartId' + j).detach() is not a function

Comment: @ Robin: $('#chartId' + j).detach() works but $('#target').append($('#chartId' + j)) does not restore the chart. Also why detach() and not remove()? Thanks

Comment: `.detach()` removes it from the DOM but keeps the events and data attached to it intact. Whereas, with `.remove()` all data and events are lost once removed.

Comment: @Gian: May I ask why you need to remove it from the DOM? Would toggling the visibility help?

Comment: yes, I have tried the .show() .hide() as suggested by jfriend00 and it works. I was wondering what the memory implications are with each of these approaches and thought it would be more efficient to free up as much memory as possible and rebuild the visualization when needed. For example, what if I want to save (JISON ?) the visualization and restore it when I log in from a different device? Thanks

Comment: In that case, the only benefit would be reducing weight on the DOM. It would, still however, be retained in memory. I'm not quite quite sure how you plan to use JISON here. It was the JS parser generator that was used to create CoffeeScript, right? :)

Comment: sorry meant JSON :-) any suggestion on this save to Json and restore?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the d3 library. Is there a way to get state data in JSON? You could 'stringify' that and save it on the server side. In session/data store.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robin. This answers my question on JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008025/using-json-data-in-d3-javascript-visualisation

Answer (score 0):

D3 doesn't support reattaching nodes that have been deleted.

`selection.remove()` doesn't completely destroy the node though, it acts quite similarly to jQuery's `detach()` method. (Using jQuery with SVG elements never ends well)

The good news is that this is pretty easy with the built-in SVG DOM.

```
// .remove() returns the detached node.
var el = d3.select('.selection').remove();
var nativeEl = el[0][0];
nativeEl.parentNode.appendChild(nativeEl);
```

Usually it would probably just be easier to show and hide these elements, but in cases like re-arranging the order of elements post-render, this can be pretty useful.